# Refresh Firebase data on android listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android app i have a listview with item from firebase database. When i am deleting an item from the listview it also deleted from firebase database correctly. The problem is that i don't know who to refresh the listview after the action of delete. Can anyone help me to retrieve data after delete?

This is the code of deleting item from listview

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete List___" );
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Post post = (Post)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    DatabaseReference del = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user-posts").child(getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostId());

                    del.setValue(null);


                }
            });

            dialogBuilder.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And this the code when i am retrieving data from database.

```
mDatabase.child(getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            mAdapter.add(post);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.d(TAG,"dataCHANGE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            Log.d(TAG,"dataREMOVE "+ dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.d(TAG,"dataMOVE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `onChildRemoved` will return to you the key of the deleted node, so you can just add this to that method:

```
String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
for (Post pt : <list_of_the_adapter> {

    if (key.equals(pt.getPostId())) {
        <list_of_the_adapter>.remove(pt);
        <adapter>.notifyDataSetChanged();

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you give me an example of <list_of_the_adapter> ?

Comment: With <list_of_the_adapter> I mean, that you should place there the list of the adapter of your list. You gave a list to the adapter when you created it, right?

Comment: You are right. It works.You made my day. Thank you very much